# Core Data fetch requests in nested tree structure

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, tree, nsfetchrequest

So, I'm just getting to really enjoy Core Data, and have started integrating it into an app I'm working on. However, I have encountered a problem for which I see no obvious solution, which is making me feel like maybe Core Data's not the right tool for the job. Here's the situation: I have a tree of `Node`s, each of which may or may not have children. There may be arbitrarily many root `Node`s. I have put together the data model using to-many relationships (from `Node` to `Node`s) with to-one inverse relationships. All that is fine.

Now, each `Node` also has a to-many relationship to `Record`s, which also have an inverse to-one relationship back to the `Node`. What I want to do is find all `Record`s which have a specific boolean attribute set to true, and are ***somewhere below*** a given `Node`. This was super easy before I was using Core Data -- I just walk the tree. However, this is time consuming, and I was hoping that Core Data would give me a way to just make a fetch request which would grab all the `Record`s I want quickly. I can see how to do it (semi) easily if I know the max depth I want to check, but what if I want to go all the way down? What if not all `Node`s have children?

Should I just walk the tree as I was doing before?

Is `NSFetchRequest` even capable of performing such a task?

Comment: really? nobody has *any* relevant experience to share?

Comment: CoreData is good for this type of task.  However, you should probably give more specifics about your data model layout, and what problem you are actually having.  Maybe even an example of what you want to fetch.

Without that information, the best I can do is tell you to use a fetch request with a predicate.  You know, you can directly span relationships with "dot" notation.

Comment: What kind of detail do you need? I have `Node <-->> Node <-->> ... <-->> Node`, and each node has `Node <-->> Record`. I want to find all `Records` which are marked `paid`, and are children of a given node (or of one of its children, or their children, etc.) I know how to use predicates, the problem is that I can't specify the number of levels ahead of time. i.e., I COULD use a predicate which looks at `child.child.records.paid == YES` or some-such, but then I ONLY get records which are EXACTLY two levels down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a core data problem, but a graph problem.  You have to do the same searching.  However, CoreData can allow you to fault in the objects.  So, you have several options, two of which are

1) Walk the tree.  You should be able to use the exact same algorithm you were using with the in-memory tree.  CoreData should just fault in the objects.  Unless you have an extremely deep tree, you should be fine.

2) Encode the parent relationship in each record.  A fair amount of updating when the tree is updated, but fetches will be quicker.

The following can be turned into a NSCompoundPredicate and assigned as the fetch predicate...  Docs say it works on CoreData, but not for sqllite - try it.

```
NSPredicate *nodePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"field = %@", value];
// Use nodePredicate to find ones that match the ones you want to find
// Then use a block predicate to see if the parent is there.
NSArray *potential = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSPredicate *parentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        Node *node = obj;
        while (node) {
            if ([node.parent.nodeId isEqualToString:targetId) return YES;
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return NO;
    }];
    NSArray *foundNodes = [potential filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand 2). I'm _already_ encoding the parent relationship in each record -- as the inverse of the children relationship. Also, how is this helpful?

Comment: Anyway, basically you're saying that the answer to my question is no, there is no better way than walking the tree?

Comment: You have to find the node of interest, then recursively search the tree from there.  If you are willing to do some extra work on insert, then you have multiple options.

1. Each node can have another to-many relationship called "parents" which contains links to each of its parent nodes.  The set of links has to be updated any time it's hierarchy is updated, but you can then do a simple search because the node part is a simple search of the "parents" list in all nodes that have paid set to YES.

Comment: ... thus completely defeating the purpose of using Core Data, since I have to manually maintain relational structure. Cool, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to edit the answer... you still get a lot from using CoreData... smaller memory footprint and automatic faults...  The solution is still walking the graph, but done as a predicate block...  if you can figure out how to embed to walk in a stored procedure... all the better

Comment: I get it. That's rad, thanks. And you think this will be faster than just walking _down_ the tree?

Comment: It depends, but it delegates the initial search for possible targets to the DB proper -- it should be able to find those "interesting" objects fairly quickly.  Then, just go back up to see if you have an "interesting" parent node.

You could, of course, do it the other way too...  First, fetch the one interesting "parent" then do a recursive search for nodes that have the "value" you want.

Comment: I'll try it. The only thing I'm concerned about is maintaining this list of parents. But it can't possibly be worse than the code I've got now, which makes it nearly impossible to move nodes around the tree.

Comment: If you use either of the walk algorithms, you don't have to maintain a list of parents.  When you create the association in CoreData, it will automatically create a two-way association, and the best part -- it will automatically manage the integrity of the relationships.